# Create 2 routes using only one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller called `Contacts` as well as my resources, but I need an action called `vendors` but if I add the route to my contacts resources I get

`contacts/:id/vendors`

I need it to be

`vendors/:id`

but without creating another controller for vendors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should help you. But I recommend you to search [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) next time, it should be more informative for you.

```
resources :contacts
get '/vendors/:id', to: 'contacts#vendor'
```